# Doctrine DQL QueryBuilder Excluding Entities where relationship exists

Tags: orm, symfony, doctrine-orm, associations, outer-join

I have two entites

```
Order
  oneToMany:
    statuses:
       targetEntity: \Status
       mappedBy: order

Status
  manyToOne:
    order:
      targetEntity: \Order
      inversedBy: status
  fields:
    code:
      type:integer
```

As you can see - one order can have more that one status at a time (statuses like 'has been shipped', 'has been paid for etc.').

I want to write a query that fetch all my Orders that do NOT have a status of 6.
I'm finding it hard to get my head round this.

Assume that I have three orders. The all have a status of '1' (new), and ONE of those orders  additionally has a status of '6' (under review). I want to retrieve only the two orders that do NOT have a status of 6.

Writing the query like so..

```
$qb->select('o')
    ->from('MyOrderBundle:Order', 'o')
    ->innerJoin('o.statuses', 'st')
    ->where(
    $qb->expr()->not(
        $qb->expr()->eq('st.code', 6)
        )
);
```

Excludes the status row of 6 from the SQL generated, but still includes the order in the result set (because the status row where the code=1 matches the condition of not being equal to 6). I need to be able to say "Exclude from my result set any entity that has an association like {something}". Is there a DQL keyword that can help me here?

-Cross posting on the doctrine user group and will update answers In both place if I find a solution.

Answer (score 3):

I worked out a way to do this eventually using a subselect, *which feels a bit hacky* but I couldn't think of any other way (where 6,7,8,9 are statuses that I want to exclude from my result set).

```
$qb->select('o')
->from('MyOrderBundle:Order', 'o')
->innerJoin('o.statuses', 'st')
->where(
    $qb->expr()->notIn(
        $qb2->select('DISTINCT(o2.id)')
        ->from('MyOrderBundle:Status', 'stat')
        ->innerJoin('stat.order','o2','WITH', $qb2->expr()->in('stat.code', (6,7,8,9)))->getDQL()
    )
);
```

Comment: This doesn't work because `notIn()` expects 2 arguments, you've only given it 1.