# symfony (doctrine): DQL query, how to exclude results?

Tags: sql, symfony, doctrine, dql

I have very basic knowledge of SQL and don't how to modify my query so it returns the expected result.

My entities `Activity` has a field **members** (a manyToMany relation). An activity can be done by several members.
I want to select all the activities a specific member **does NOT** take part into. I know the member's id (my variable `$selfId`).

Here's what I'm doing in *ActivityRepository*:

```
public function getCollectiveActivities($selfId)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('a');
    $qb->join('a.members', 'm')
       ->where('m.id != :selfId')
       ->setParameter('selfId', $selfId);

    return $qb
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
}
```

My problem: when an activity "owns" two or more members, if one of them has $selfId as id, this activity ends up in my query results.
But since one of the members of this activity has the id $selfId, **it should not be returned**. What am I doing wrong?

### EDIT

I think I need to be more restrictive, I just don't know how.
Let's say I have two activities:

```
activity1 which is owned by member1 and member2
activity2 which is owned by member3 and member4
```

$selfId = 3 (this means I don't want to fetch activities owned by member3)

From what I understand, the join clause might return lines like these:

```
activity1 | memberId: 1 (different from selfId = 3 so activity1 will be fetched)
activity1 | memberId: 2 (different from selfId = 3 so activity1 will be fetched)
activity2 | memberId: 3 (= selfId so activity2 shouldn't be fetched)
activity2 | memberId: 4 (different from selfId = 3 so activity2 WILL be fetched. PROBLEM???)
```

### EDIT 2

Others already faced the same problem and found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10638926/doctrine-dql-querybuilder-excluding-entities-where-relationship-exists) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25121117/doctrine-querybuilder-exclude-articles-linked-to-specific-themes), but they seem a bit hacky. Any clue on how to improve them would be welcome.

Answer (score 2):

You have to specifically select the results you want to be hydrated. The problem you're seeing is that you're just selecting activity.

Then when you call $activity->getMembers() members are lazy loaded, and this doesn't take into account your query.

You can avoid this like so:

```
public function getCollectiveActivities($selfId)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('a');
    $qb->addSelect('m');
    $qb->join('a.members', 'm')
       ->where('m.id != :selfId')
       ->setParameter('selfId', $selfId);

    return $qb
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
}
```

This means your fetched activity will already have its members hydrated and restricted by your query condition.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but adding  `$qb->addSelect('m');` doesn't change anything to my query result. I still get the unwanted activity.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function getCollectiveActivities($selfId)
{

    return $this->createQueryBuilder('a')
        ->join('a.members', 'm')
        ->where($qb->expr()->neq('c.selfId', $selfId))     
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();

}
```

Comment: 'neq'  is 'not equal to' , i hope which may help to complete your query. All the best.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You meant **->where($qb->expr()->neq('m.id', $selfId))**

    Anyway,  I think using expr()->neq() is strictly equivalent to what I'm doing, it didn't change anything to my result.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up adapting [a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25121117/doctrine-querybuilder-exclude-articles-linked-to-specific-themes) posted by @NtskX.

```
public function getCollectiveActivities($selfId)
{
    $qbMyCollectives = $this->createQueryBuilder('ca');
    $qbMyCollectives
        ->select('ca.id')
        ->leftJoin('ca.members', 'm')
        ->where('m.id = :selfId')
        ->setParameter('selfId', $selfId);

    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('a');
    $qb
        ->where($qb->expr()->notIn('a.id', $qbMyCollectives->getDQL()))
        ->setParameter('selfId', $selfId); // I had to declare the parameter one more time

    return $qb
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
}
```

I really thought someone would show up with a better way to do the join, so any other answer is much welcome.